# plugin manager fault installation

Tags: qgis-plugins

i have posted once a question about not getting the "get more" icon within the plugin manager tab.
I solved my problem by specifying the proxy server that supports the network to which my PC (windows7 OS) is linked.
However, a very odd thing happened while i was giving a training course on QGIS. Several of the attendees used their own laptop (all windows) and none of them got the get more icon within the plugin manager.
All of them downloaded QGIS Dufour from the QGIS website and followed the straightforward installation process. Why this bizarre thing is happening? How can i solve the problem?